# window.location subject to querystring limitation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
   window.location = "/Home/GetCustomers?" + $('#myForm').serialize();
});
```

Is using window.location subject to querystring size limitation? For instance, if my form has many parameters to serialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window.location can't be longer than whatever URL length limit the user's browser enforces.  This varies from browser to browser; the shortest one is Internet Explorer, which is 2083 characters.

Comment: I didn't realize this was a browser specific limitation.  Good to know. I also found this related information: https://web.archive.org/web/20150519072531/http://classicasp.aspfaq.com:80/forms/what-is-the-limit-on-querystring/get/url-parameters.html

Answer (score 2):

The spec for URL length does not dictate a minimum or maximum URL length, but implementation varies by browser. On Windows: Opera supports ~4050 characters, IE 4.0+ supports exactly 2083 characters, Netscape 3 -> 4.78 support up to 8192 characters before causing errors on shut-down, and Netscape 6 supports ~2000 before causing errors on start-up.